# How To Use host tag In dhcp.conf

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, static-ip, dhcpd

My question is simple. I tried to assign a fixed IP address to wlan0 connected users using dhcp.conf. From configuration file:

```
host clientA{
  hardware ethernet 00:80:c6:f6:72:00;
  fixed-address 192.168.1.50;
}
```

My confusion is `clientA`. What can I use instead of that? If that is a hostname, where do I find it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClientA` it's hostname for DHCP server config file.

Comment: Where I Find It @Alexander

Comment: @ksivasuriyaprakash you could run `hostname` in command line.

Comment: That's Also Resides on /etc/hostname. Thanks For Fast Response.............

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the client is configured, it may or may not send the hostname when it makes a DHCP request.  But, as the example shows, you can access it via the MAC address.  On my own home set up, I use the hostname field in the dhcpd.conf so I know which machine it is (livingroom-tv, my-desktop, wifes-iphone, etc) and depend on the MAC address `hardware ethernet` option to determine which machine is actually getting that particular IP.  DNS is handled separately with a fake domain (my.house) because only a few machines actually need DNS entries (for me/my convenience) and is not integrated in any way with DHCP.  Almost all of my static-dynamic MAC address based IPs are given out to control access - I have a VERY short lease time, and when the kids need to be blocked from access, I simply change their default gateway or point them at a second DNS server that restricts where they can go/what they can do (ie, on their  phone facebook.com may say "you should be doing homework!" :) )